# How can I get the x,y,z axes in forge viewer which is similar to HUD in Navisworks?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, hud

I want to show X,Y,Z axes in forge viewer at the bottom-left corner like Navisworks. I can create the axes lines (described [here](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/12/understand-the-coordinate-system-of-view-and-data-api-with-axishelper-extension.html)) in a certain position of the viewer. But, as expected, whenever I navigate to somewhere the axes also moves. I want it to be placed at the bottom-left corner every time and syncing with the viewer X,Y,Z axes. The Navisworks axes in HUD is like below -

[image]

Please share some good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Forge Viewer doesn't offer this feature out-of-the-box but it should be pretty straightforward to implement something similar yourself.

I'd recommend using the approach used by the viewer's "view cube" (in the top-right corner). That cube is actually rendered in its own `<canvas>` element, and overlaid on top of the viewer canvas. You could create your own `<canvas>` element in the bottom-right corner, use standard three.js (specifically version 71 that's included in Forge Viewer) to render your axes there, and update their orientation based on the viewer's `Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT`.